# Python How to drop rows of Pandas DataFrame whose value in a certain column is NaN

Tags: python, pandas, axis

I have this DataFrame and want only the records whose "Total" column is not NaN ,and records when A~E has more than two NaN:

```
A  B  C  D      E  Total
1  1  3  5      5    8
1  4  3  5      5   NaN
3  6  NaN NaN  NaN   6
2  2  5  9     NaN   8
```

..i.e. something like df.dropna(....) to get this resulting dataframe:

```
A  B  C  D      E  Total
1  1  3  5      5    8
2  2  5  9     NaN   8
```

Here's my code

```
import pandas as pd

dfInputData = pd.read_csv(path)
dfInputData = dfInputData.dropna(axis=1,how = 'any')
RowCnt = dfInputData.shape[0]
```

But it looks like no modification has been made even error

Please help!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with count all columns without `Total` for number of missing values and not misisng values in `Total`:

```
df = df[df.drop('Total', axis=1).isna().sum(axis=1).le(2) & df['Total'].notna()]
print (df)
   A  B    C    D    E  Total
0  1  1  3.0  5.0  5.0    8.0
3  2  2  5.0  9.0  NaN    8.0
```

Or filter columns between `A:E`:

```
df = df[df.loc[:, 'A':'E'].isna().sum(axis=1).le(2) & df['Total'].notna()]
print (df)
   A  B    C    D    E  Total
0  1  1  3.0  5.0  5.0    8.0
3  2  2  5.0  9.0  NaN    8.0
```

Comment: but I can't output the DataFrame ,it can only display the previous column of Nan

Comment: @tongtong - can you be more specific? Can you change sample data  for see problem?